# Cannot use gem and ruby command after install on Vista

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-vista, rubygems

I installed Ruby and Ruby on Rails yesterday on Vista 32bit using the directions on this site: http://rubyonrails.org/down

So I downloaded the installer, then Gems, then I downloaded rails with Gems.

Now I can't use the Gem or Ruby commands in the command line... so I assume there's something wrong with the environment variables, but I hav eno idea how to set them up in Vista or what to put.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To set up the environment variables, do this

1. Fire up the start menu
2. **Right-Click** on `Computer` and select `Properties`
3. Click `Advanced system settings` in the left-hand bar, and confirm the UAC prompt
4. Select the `Advanced` tab (it's 3rd)
5. Click `Environment Variables...` (at the bottom)
6. In the top box (`User variables for XXX`) either find the entry for `PATH`, or click new to create the entry.
   If there is already a `PATH` use semi-colons to seperate each directory listed in it
7. Put `c:\ruby\bin` (change if you installed ruby somewhere else) in.
8. Click OK a lot of times to close all the windows we opened.
9. Restart your command prompt.

`gem` and `ruby` and `irb` should now all work. Whoever said that GUI tools are slower than command line tools. pshaw!

Answer (score 2):

In the command line window type `PATH` then hit return, do you see `ruby.exe` on the `PATH` environment variable?

If you installed ruby to say `c:\ruby` then it'll be `c:\ruby\bin\`.

Looks like it may be missing from the path.

Comment: it's not there... and I can't figure out how to add it in Vista

Answer (score 1):

Add your ruby bin directory to your PATH environment variable, go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings, then go to the Advanced tab, Environment Variables, then edit your PATH variable and append the path to the ruby binaries install i.e.  **;C:\ruby\bin**